# How do I know which reference 'refers' to a vector?

Tags: java, arrays, vector, reference, tostring

So I was given this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.Point;
import static java.lang.System.out;
class Polygon
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
      Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
      out.print ("the number of vertices in the polygon: ");
      int n = in.nextInt ();
      Point[] v = new Point[n];
      int x = 0;
      int y = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
        out.print ("vertex " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        x = in.nextInt ();
        y = in.nextInt ();
        v[i] = new Point (x, y);
      }
      out.println ();

      out.println (toString (v));
      out.println (perimeter (v));
      }

 public static double perimeter (Point[] v)
 {
   double perimeter = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
     perimeter += v[i].distance (v[(i + 1) % v.length]);
   return perimeter;
 }

public static String toString (Point[] v)
{
  StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder ("[");
  for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
     s.append ("(" + v[i].x + ", " + v[i].y + ")");
  s.append ("]");
  return s.toString ();
}
}
```

So basically, the program displays the String representation of all the vertices and the perimeter of the polygon.

But in a question, I was asked:

Draw the vector containing the vertices of the polygon. Which references refer to this vector when the method perimeter is executed and which when the method toString is executed?

So I already drew the vector so no need to worry about that. But what do they mean by 'Which reference refers to this vector' in the 2nd part of the question?

Answer (score 0):

They mean, how many variables are pointing at (referencing) the vector data in memory.  For example, the variable (or "reference") `v` "*refer[s] to this vector*" when `perimeter()` is executed